# How do I calculate my cylinders volume in a diffrent method in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.*;

public class UG3 {



    public static void main (String[] arg) {



            String radius = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input Radius");
            String height = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input Height");// input radius and height.

       try {  // trying to make sure that the user inputs information otherwise it will cancel.

            int rad = Integer.parseInt(radius);
            int hei = Integer.parseInt(height);


            NumberFormat r = NumberFormat.getInstance();

            r.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
            r.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The volume of the cylinder is approximately "+ r.format(volume) +"CM^3"); // output results. // Here is the problem " volume " is: "cannot be resolved".   



            int yes = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to find the volume of a cylinder once more?", "", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

            if(yes == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) { 
                main(arg);
            }

            else  {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You'r welcome! \n \n Click 'OK' to exit", "Cylinder.", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }


        catch (NumberFormatException e) { // cancel.

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry but you have to enter radius and height to complete the task."); 
        }




     } //main

     public static double volume(double radius, double height){ 
         return Math.PI * Math.pow(radius,2) * height; 

     }  

}//Cylinder
```

I wrote "comments" to show you where. Anyway, "volume cannot be resolved" why?
Did I miss to delete something from the first method? is something missing? Can't get my head around it. :S

Comment: You never parsed/converted radius and height into a number (before the if statement). In fact, you *should* be getting an error `bad operand types for binary operator '>'`... is that what you're getting? *Always* include the error if you have one.

Comment: thanks! but I managed to solve it with try -catch  :) How do I solve the volume calculation in a new method? :D

Comment: Did you try just using the method you already have defined??

Comment: Yeah but every time I try to move my calculations to a different method I get a lot of errors. saying in line 26 "r.format(VOLUME)" volume is undefined.

Comment: I don't see what that code has to do with your `getVolume` method. What are "a lot of errors"? As I said before, if you're getting errors, tell us what they are.

Comment: volume cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: "JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The volume of the cylinder is approximately "+ r.format(VOLUME) +"CM^3");"

Comment: Show your actual code in your question please. Java is case sensitive, `VOLUME` is not the same as `volume` which IS defined.

Comment: I have edit my post, sorry about that.

Comment: I resolved the issue, Editing my post soon.

Comment: I rolled back your question to a version with the "original question" (after some changes though). Please don't edit your question to tell us that you've fixed something. Either mark the answer which helped you to do that as "correct", or post an answer yourself to explain what you've did to solve your problem. Also don't edit your question to ask something new, create a new question instead.

Comment: I'm sorry. Didn't mean to upset anyone.

Answer (score 0):

`radius` and `height` are `String` variables, but you're trying to compare them with `int` values (e.g. `radius >= 1`).

If all you're trying to do here is to make sure that the user gave you some information, you could do a simple test for `null` and/or the empty string (e.g. `radius != null && radius != ""`).

*** Edit to add do-while ***

1. Put the do-while around the try-catch.
2. Use `yes == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION` as the *while* condition.
3. Get rid of the

   ```
   if (yes == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
       //....
   else
       //....
   ```

   logic.

Comment: I solved it with try [{} catch (NumberFormatException e) {}

Comment: I tried to do with do-while and tried to the code you gave me but it didn't work. :S any other suggestions how i can make a do- while work? witht he program I have? I have edited my code! =)

Comment: `radius > ""` Checks for a nonempty string? Looks more like a syntax error to me :(.

Comment: Thanks @Tom, fixed. It's OBE at this point given the OP is using try/catch, but yes, you are correct.

Comment: I don't think that this `radius != ""` will ever be true, since I don't think that `showInputDialog` returns String  literals.

Comment: Perhaps, @Tom. Perhaps `!radius.isEmpty()`? Three strikes and I'm out, so fingers crossed.

Comment: Yes, that would work. Important to know is this: [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/513832), but since `!radius.equals("")` looks kind of "silly" it is better/prettier to use `!radius.isEmpty()`.